# Can the distance between 2 non-empty sets be infinite?

Tags: metric-spaces, infinity

Intuitively I would immediately assume no, but that's not how things usually work in math and considering there are different kinds of infinities I haven't been able to find the answer.

Here's my definition of the distance between 2 sets:

$d(A,B) = \inf{\{||\vec a - \vec b||:\vec a \in A, \vec b \in B\}}$

Comment: What is a distance for two general sets? Or, do you mean sets in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: This was a question on my exam. The title was all the given information and we simply had to answer yes or no. Though 'our' definition of distance was: $d(A,B) = \inf{\{||\vec a - \vec b||:\vec a \in A, \vec b \in B\}}$

Comment: It depends on whether “your” definition of a metric space admits infinite distances.

Comment: Please add the definition of "distance between sets" to the question. I'd do it myself, but you've got the lovely TeX all ready to go in your comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The distance between two sets of the same metric space is defined as:

$$d(A,B) = \inf_{x\in A,\ y\in B} d(x,y)$$

That means that if $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ then $d(x,y) \geq d(A,B)$.

Now, $d(x,y)$ is always finite in a metric space so $d(A,B)$ must be too.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x$ be an element of $A$ and let $y$ be an element of $B$. We know that $\|x-y\|$ is a real number $r$ and so $d(A,B)$ must be at most $r$ by the definition of $d(A,B)$, hence $d(A,B)$ is finite.